# Will dnf-automatic update packages in yum.repos.d even though that's a yum directory?

Tags: centos, yum, centos8, dnf

**Environment:** CentOS 8

**Package:** NGINX 1.16

I installed, enabled and confirmed dnf-automatic with the following commands.

```
$ sudo dnf install dnf-automatic
$ sudo systemctl enable --now dnf-automatic.timer
$ systemctl list-timers *dnf-*
```

I installed NGINX and the instructions have me place the repo in a yum folder.

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
```

Will dnf-automatic keep nginx updated if it is located in `yum.repos.d` or does the repo need to be placed in a different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DNF Configuration Reference](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html):

> DNF by default uses the global configuration file
>   at `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` and all `*.repo` files found
>   under `/etc/yum.repos.d`. The latter is typically used for repository
>   configuration and takes precedence over global configuration.

So the answer is **yes**, it does.